# Pass Array From Main Form to Other Form and then Put it in ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

I Need to pass array from main form to other form in VB.NET and then put the value of the array in ComboBox. I try to use below code, but there are error "Value cannot be null." "Parameter name: item" appear.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you.

```
Dim kodeb() As String = FrmBarang.kode
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(kodeb)
```

Comment: It would be easier to do if you werent using default form instances

Comment: The way I see it, you have two options. 1.)Use global array variable.  2.)Add a new constructor to the form class that takes an array as a parameter.

Comment: You could also create add a public property to the second form's class.  Then, in the first form, create an instance of the second form and set it's array property to the first form's array.

Comment: Remember, forms are actually instances of that particular Form's class.  So, if you are not programatically declaring new instances of the form, it's more difficult to get the instance of the form you are looking for.  For instance, In your above code, you are attempting to get the .kode object from the FrmBarang class.  FrmBarang is the class of the form and not the form itself.  However, if you had declared the form programatically `Dim myFrmBarang as new FrmBarang` then you could reference that form object easily.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael...except that instance would most certainly be an invisible instance and not contain the relevant data required.  Your original suggestions were spot on, however.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `FormA` generates array and creates `FormB`, and then passes the array

In Pseudo-code

```
public class FormA

    private sub onButton1_click()
        dim a(10) as string
        ' generate array
        loop
            ' add items to array
        end loop

        ' lets open another form and pass the array
        dim f as new FormB(a) 'constructor of form B accepts array
        f.show()
    end sub

end class 

public class FormB

    public sub new(byval a() as string)

        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(a);

    end sub

end class
```

This is just one of ways. Since your question is not specific enough, try to make best out of it